# Is there a garbage collection in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Java has a Garbage Collection. But you should take precautions to avoid the memory leak.  Does that apply to kotlin?  Is there a memory leak in Kotlin?  Is there a Garbage Collection at Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Yes

**(Not so) Long explanation:**

kotlin actually runs on JVM as well as Java. So java does not have any garbage collection. Java is just a programming language. The garbage collection part comes from Java Virtual Machine. Kotlin being an revolutionary language still depends on JVM. Actually any language depending on the JVM automatically have *Garbage Collection.*

Comment: Are the things that we avoid from memory leak in java valid for kotlin?  or does kotlin automatically regulate them?

Comment: Most of the Kotlin calls translate to traditional, valid Java calls. I say "most" because Kotlin compiler can take some shortcuts that are valid for the JVM, but not for the Java language as it is. That way, it is safe to assume that you need to be as careful with Kotlin as you should be when using plain-old Java.

Comment: @HasanKucuk There are instances where Kotlin will avoid holding references to the outer class, see https://proandroiddev.com/how-kotlin-helps-you-avoid-memory-leaks-e2680cf6e71e